# Trying to add new variables to the filter function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I am trying to add new variable to my filter function but I am unsure of the syntax and I was wondering if would help:

```
  var info = req.survey
  var lang = req.query.lang
  var sender = req.survey.sender
  const compileCardData = (category, lang, survey) => ({ category, lang, questions: survey.filter(q => q.category === category && q.sender.language[0] === lang) })
 
  // check whether we want to redirect to thank you page
  var everythingIsAnswered = info.survey.every(i => i.category === 'fakebutton' || _.isNumber(i.answer))
  if (req.query.redirect && /http/.test(req.query.redirect) && everythingIsAnswered) return res.redirect(req.query.redirect)

  // compile output
  var cardsData = [compileCardData('product', lang, info.survey), compileCardData('delivery', lang, info.survey), compileCardData('packaging', lang, info.survey)]
```

As you can see I am adding the variable "lang" to compileCardData to ensure it's actually the language sent via the endpoint but I cannot get the syntax right :/ . The reason is I am filtering it out from a different variable sender at the same time survey is being used. what am I missing. Can we do this in a filter function or do I need to separate it? Thanks :)

Comment: What error you are having?

Comment: Sorry had to edit the question but the error is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'language' of undefined"

Comment: It's because we a filtering out through survey but I need to filter out through survery.sender for another attribute in the same filter method

Comment: `info.survey` is `req.survey.survey`, does it correct?

Comment: I just would more or less like it to be one filter function if that makes sense?